# Big Endian Vs Little Endian Padding Issue

Tags: c, operating-system, endianness

In my code there is a structure which have padding issues. I fixed them and my code is running fine on a little endian machine. Can there be a chance that this stucture cause a problem for a big endian machine ??

Comment: Do you mind explaining what this "padding issue" is? Or, if it's common for little/big endian problems, ignore my comment.

Comment: actually I have some static arrays of sizes not the multiple of 4(Code is for 32 bit systems). I fixed them by just making them by making them multiple of 8. I send data to some remote client via send().

Comment: No, endianness doesn't affect padding.  A member of a struct is the same size, just the byte order is different.  Assuming both compilers agree about the size.  These sort of problems made XML very popular.

Comment: If you are using bit-fields in your structure as well, you may also be affected by bit-ordering and padding issues on that level. If this is an issue for you, let me know, I can elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep the following in mind:

- Whenever doing data communication, the endianess of the *communication protocol* is what matters. All data communication protocols have (should have) a specified endianess. Big endian is probably most common, because back in the days where CRC calculations were done with digital electonic gates rather than software, the checksum itself had to be big endian.

(This can lead to quite obscure protocols, like the industry standard field bus CANopen, where all integers in the sent data must be little endian, but the identifier and checksum must be big endian.)

- Struct padding will always cause issues when you are writing portable code. Code like `send(&my_struct, sizeof(my_struct)` is never portable! Because it will send the data *and* any padding bytes. And padding bytes may be anywhere inside the struct and not just in the end. If you need to write truly portable code, you *cannot* use structs/unions for the data protocol, everything needs to be stored in arrays of bytes or similar, where the data is guaranteed to be allocated in adjacent cells. Struct padding has nothing to do with endianess, but rather of the CPU instruction set.

(Motorola CPUs have traditionally had better support for reading and storing at unaligned addresses, while Intel derivates have alignment requirements and are therefore more prone to use padding. As it happens, Motorola were with the big endians and Intel were with the little endians. So by coincidence, little endian CPUs are more likely to have padding, but this is *only* because of the CPU instruction set and not because of the endianess itself.)

Answer (score 0):

A structure, in C, is a way of representing data in memory. (It gives "structure" to memory.)

Any conversion from "struct" to "sequence of bytes" that just casts the "struct" bit away, and uses whatever underlying byte representation C is using is going to be affected by endianness. (And padding. Maybe other issues too, like pointers, sizeof(some-integral-type), etc.)

I suspect you're doing something like this:

```
// Some non-standard way to get rid of padding in Foo
struct Foo
{
  // Some fields...
}

// Meanwhile, in a function somewhere...
fwrite(a_foo, sizeof(a_foo), 1, fp);
```

Maybe you're not calling `fwrite`, maybe it's `send`, but yes, if you're doing serialization like this, you are going to be effected by endianness.

Comment: Yes your assumption is right. Actually I have some static arrays of sizes not the multiple of 4(Code is for 32 bit systems). I fixed them by just making them by making them multiple of 8. I send data to some remote client via send()